# loading options to select using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using JqueryAjax to load options in Select element.

```
<div>
    <select id="roleType" name="roleType" 
             onclick="loadRoleTypes();">
               <option value="s">Select</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

JqueryAjax

```
function loadRoleTypes()
{           
    $('#roleType').empty().append('<option>select</option>');        
    $.ajax({
            url: '/ci/ajaxcall/loadRoles.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"userCode": userCode},
            success: function(response) {
              var array = response.value;
              if (array != '')
              {
                for (i in array) {                        
                 $("#roleType").append("<option>"+array[i].ROLE_TYPE+"</option>");
               }

              }

            },
            error: function(x, e) {

            }

        });
}
```

here i am getting option values as drop down when i click select element.but i cant select a particular option.how to solve this

Comment: are you trying to load drop down when you first time click on it or you want to load it when click on it everytime?

Comment: value attribute is missing in option element

Comment: @pankajparkar, it is fine if no value attribute is mentioned as it will take label as value of the option.

Comment: i want to load when click and i have to select an option from the loaded list

Comment: same problem exists when i am putting values to option

Comment: Where is `userCode` defined?

Comment: thats hidden.My ajax ouptput works fine

Comment: does ajax returns data properly?

Comment: yes.here my actual problem is i cant select an option from the loaded list

Comment: you are loading options when click on dropdown box. when you try to select option from dropdown you are clicking on it again and hence it will make a ajax call and try to load all options again. You can make a code to load options for the first click only and then select your desired option.

Comment: Interesting question. May be you can change the onclick event to onmousedown, but I know this solution may not help you but you can give it a try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you can't select an option is that every time you click the selectbox(Including the option set) the function called `loadRoleTypes()` is being called.You can try checking the number of options in your selectbox.Or you could check on any other conditions.

```
function loadRoleTypes()
{           
if ($('#roleType').find("option").size() == 1) {  //Check condition here
    $('#roleType').empty().append('<option>select</option>');        
    $.ajax({
            url: '/ci/ajaxcall/loadRoles.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"userCode": userCode},
            success: function(response) {
              var array = response.value;
              if (array != '')
              {
                for (i in array) {                        
                 $("#roleType").append("<option>"+array[i].ROLE_TYPE+"</option>");
               }

              }

            },
            error: function(x, e) {

            }

        });
}
}
```